# Validating JWT token using x5c claim from jwks, good or bad practise?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect, access-token, jwk

I am implementing a Azure AD authentication scheme currently, and have been reading up on validating accesstokens, but have found conflicting information about using the certificate from the x5c claim to validate a tokens validity.

As I am only working with Azure AD, I am getting the jwks set from the jwks_url found in [https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TENANTID]/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5BTENANTID%5D/.well-known/openid-configuration), which is hardcoded in my application and not supplied or extracted from the accesstoken in any way.

I can't see any issues in using the certificate, as it is being retrieved from a trusted URL, but is there something I am not aware of?  I have not done that much work with token based authentication.

Comment: Sorry but it's unclear what the question here is. Are you hardcoding the PKIX cert value from the `jwks_url` in your applicationnd want to know if that's ok? Or is the question 'should I be using the jwks_uri'?

Comment: The keys might change if AzureAD chooses to rotate the keys.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary No, the only thing I am hardcoding is the tenant part of the openid-configuration URL.

I am then using that to discover the jwks_url and downloading the keys from there.

I just saw mentioned that I should calculate the key based on the jwk, and not use the x5c value, and I can't for the life of me see any good reason not to use it.

Comment: @FlyveHest No, what you're doing is perfectly correct and valid. 'calculate the key based on the jwk' - can you show me where you read that?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary It was in another SO question, but I can't for the life of me find it now.

I can't seem to accept your comment as an answer, though.

Comment: Comment by @ErmiyaEskandary accepted as answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77110344/validating-jwt-token-using-x5c-claim-from-jwks-good-or-bad-practise?noredirect=1#comment135956055_77110344